# Web pages download to desktop instead of load?

Tags: magento, migration

I am in the middle of migrating a Magento site over to a new server. I followed instructions provided in this video to a T-

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OiWmZFxrZns

However, now when I try to access the transferred site, any pages just download to my desktop instead of displaying in browser.

I have *never* encountered this before. Have you? Does anyone know what this could be? I apologize if this is too broad, but I'm wondering if maybe it's something I have to change in a file like .htaccess or something

Help!

Comment: Usually, that happens when the server delivers the pages with a document-type of "application/download", or something of the like. Have a look at your HTTP headers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I suspected- it was the .htaccess file. I fixed the issue by deleting the file altogether, though I'm sure I want only able to get away with that because I migrated everything into a subdirectory to begin with rather than the root. I am unsure if this will still be a viable solution for those experiencing the same problem in a root directory.